# Excel: Lock and protect only filled cells in entire excel report

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to lock all filled cells(only) in all sheets in a excel report?? I will be happy if there is excel property for this.If not vba code is fine. I found vba code but we have to give sheet name. Like that I have so many sheets I can`t give names of all sheets.

VBA Code:

```
  Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
For Each cl In Sheets("Sheet1").Cells
    If cl = blank Then
        cl.Locked = False
        Else
        cl.Locked = True
    End If
Next
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Sheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End Sub
```

Please suggest a better way for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can access a sheet by index instead of name

Comment: @AndreyGordeev:Thanks for your answer. but i`ll have to mention all sheet index above in my code right??? And what about performance of the action??? It`ll take so much time to do this I guess. Like it has to do it for more 2 lakh cells in each sheet,and some 12 sheets are there. Please suggest a better way for this.

Answer (score 0):

By `Filled Cells` I am assuming, Cell has `Formulas` or `Constants` or `Comments`.

See this example which you can incorporate in your code. This doesn't loop through every cell but makes use of `SpecialCells`

**UNTESTED**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Cells.Locked = False

        On Error Resume Next

        Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Rng.Locked = True

        Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        Rng.Locked = True

        Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
        Rng.Locked = True

        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to apply it for all worksheets then simply loop through all the worksheets

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            .Cells.Locked = False

            On Error Resume Next

            Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            Rng.Locked = True

            Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            Rng.Locked = True

            Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
            Rng.Locked = True

            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP (from comments)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws

            .UnProtect

            .Cells.Locked = False

            On Error Resume Next

            Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            Rng.Locked = True

            Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            Rng.Locked = True

            Set Rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
            Rng.Locked = True

            On Error GoTo 0

           .Protect
           .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth : Thanks for the answer. I`m actually a big fan of you. The above vba code will work for filled cells??? I`m actually didnt get your logic here. Please be more specific about explanation. When should I call this function??

Comment: Yes it will work for filled cells. I can explain what `SpecialCells` does but if you check the Excel Help, `SpecialCells` have been covered nicely.

Comment: Siddharth : Thanks, alright I`ll find out about SpecialCells, but this function should be called in 'aftersave' event right?

Comment: No it has to be used in `Workbook_BeforeSave`. Let me update the code above. See Followup in few moments

Comment: Updated it :) Let me know if you face any issues as I have not tested it

Comment: Siddharth: I copy pasted your code to a new excel file, and tried to save file by filling few cells. I still see filled cells are editable.

Comment: Did you protect the sheets as you have done in your original post? You need to protect the sheet for locked property to work.